# Inserting new rows using dplyr / data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Sample data

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(year = c(rep(1980:1994, each = 9), rep(1995, times = 8), rep(1996:2012, each = 9), 
                          rep(2013, times = 7), rep(2014, times = 9)),
                 ref.doy = sample(120:180, 312, replace = T),
                 x = rnorm(312))
```

For each year, if no. of `ref.doy` is not 9, then I want to insert additional new rows which is the just the copy of the last row.

For e.g. if for 1995, there are only 8 `ref.doy`, I want to copy the 8th row make it 9th row. If 2013, there are only 8 `ref.doy`, then I want to copy the 7th row and duplicate it as 8th and 9th row and so on.

The solution I have at the moment is a for-loop:

```
x <- df %>% group_by(year) %>% dplyr::mutate(y.length = n())
year.vec <- 1980:2014
temp.list <- list()

for(y in seq_along(year.vec)){

  yr <- year.vec[y]
  temp <- x %>% dplyr::filter(year == yr)  

  if(unique(temp$y.length) != 9) {

    lastrow <- temp[nrow(temp), ]
    lastrow.repeat <- as.data.frame(lapply(lastrow, rep, 9 - nrow(temp))) 
    full.data  <- rbind(data.frame(temp), lastrow.repeat)         
    temp.list[[y]] <- full.data

    } else {
    temp.list[[y]] <- temp
  }
}

newdata <- rbindlist(temp.list)
```

I need some help to do it within `dplyr` or `data.table` itself.

Comment: if you are using sample, please set a seed before you run your code with `set.seed()`. Otherwise the outcome is not reproducible.

Comment: okay. I will do that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your last two year's data which has 5 and 9 entries in 2013 and 2014 respectively as sample. We `filter` the groups which has less than 9 rows and for those groups we repeat the last row for `9 - n()` times and add these rows to original dataframe using `bind_rows`.

```
df1 <- tail(df, 14)

library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
    bind_rows(df1 %>%
               group_by(year) %>%
               #suggested by @Henrik
               filter(n() < 9) %>%
               slice(rep(n(), 9 - n()))) %>%
     arrange(year)


#   year ref.doy          x
#1  2013     126  0.9171749
#2  2013     168 -2.6609228
#3  2013     167  1.1102771
#4  2013     120 -0.4849876
#5  2013     167  0.2306168
#6  2013     167  0.2306168
#7  2013     167  0.2306168
#8  2013     167  0.2306168
#9  2013     167  0.2306168
#10 2014     164 -0.2951578
#11 2014     158  0.8719650
#12 2014     149 -0.3484724
#13 2014     129  0.5185038
#14 2014     120 -0.3906850
#15 2014     147 -1.0927872
#16 2014     150  1.2100105
#17 2014     143  0.7409000
#18 2014     148  1.7242622
```

---

Applying this on original dataframe and we check the number of rows for each `year`.

```
df2 <- df %>% 
          bind_rows(df %>%
                      group_by(year) %>%
                      filter(n() < 9) %>%
                      slice(rep(n(), 9 - n()))) %>%
          arrange(year)


df2 %>%
   group_by(year) %>%
   summarise(no_of_rows = n())
# A tibble: 35 x 2
# year no_of_rows
#   <dbl>      <int>
# 1  1980          9
# 2  1981          9
# 3  1982          9
# 4  1983          9
# 5  1984          9
# 6  1985          9
# 7  1986          9
# 8  1987          9
# 9  1988          9
#10  1989          9
# ... with 25 more rows
```

---

Or as @Henrik mentioned, the most easiest approach would be to take the last row of each group and repeat it `9 - n()` times irrespective.

```
df %>% 
   group_by(year) %>% 
   slice(c(1:n(), rep(n(), 9 - n())))
```

Comment: 1995 also has 8 years of data. I want the answer to be generaliseable to any combination of `ref.doy`

Comment: @Henrik yeah..I think it can be considered in this case. I was confused if OP needs 9 distinct `ref.doy` or 9 rows. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry for this late reply but yes, I just need to the number of rows or entries per year to be 9.

Comment: @RonakShah Perhaps `df %>% group_by(year) %>% slice(c(1:n(), rep(n(), 9 - n())))` would work (analogous to my [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52587474/inserting-new-rows-using-dplyr-data-table/52587588#comment92111385_52587616))?

Comment: @Henrik awesome! Completely makes sense. Updated the answer with your suggestion. I didn't read the comment earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Using [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, ri := rowid(year)]

df2 <- df[CJ(year = year, ri = 1:9, unique = TRUE), on = .(year, ri)
          ][, (2:3) := lapply(.SD, zoo::na.locf), .SDcols = 2:3
            ][, ri := NULL][]
```

which gives the desired result:

> ```
> > df2[year %in% c(1995,2013)]
>     year ref.doy           x
>  1: 1995     160  1.05418102
>  2: 1995     170  1.14526311
>  3: 1995     167 -0.57746800
>  4: 1995     179  2.00248273
>  5: 1995     146  0.06670087
>  6: 1995     139  1.86685184
>  7: 1995     144 -1.35090269
>  8: 1995     120  0.02098359
>  9: 1995     120  0.02098359
> 10: 2013     179  0.43528895
> 11: 2013     126  0.71517841
> 12: 2013     126  0.91717492
> 13: 2013     168 -2.66092280
> 14: 2013     167  1.11027710
> 15: 2013     120 -0.48498760
> 16: 2013     167  0.23061683
> 17: 2013     167  0.23061683
> 18: 2013     167  0.23061683
> ```

What this does:

1. `df[, ri := rowid(year)]` adds a rownumber by `year`
2. Then join with a reference table (`CJ(year = year, ri = 1:9, unique = TRUE)`) which has nine rows for each year. The result will now contain empty rows for the years that did not have nine rows.
3. Fill the empty rows with `(2:3) := lapply(.SD, zoo::na.locf), .SDcols = 2:3`
4. Finally, remove the `ri` column as it is no longer needed with `ri := NULL`

---

A better alternative as posted by @Henrik in the comments:

```
df2 <- df[ , .SD[c(1:.N, rep(.N, 9 - .N))], by = year]
```